# ifstream fails to read

Tags: c++, object, ifstream

I'm creating two functions to save and load a object into the program.

The save function aparently saves the object successfully:

```
void Game::SaveGame()
{
std::string filename = "saves/miner-save-" + currentDate() + ".gem";

std::ofstream outfile;
outfile.open(filename.c_str(), std::ios::binary);

outfile.write((char *)(&myGame), sizeof(Game));

if (outfile.fail())
    std::cout << "write failed" << std::endl;

outfile.close();

std::cout << myGame->myMiner->getX(); //debug purposes : prints 25

}
```

The problem seems to be in the load function, because the value returned from a integer of the object that is read is incorrect.

```
void Game::LoadGame()
{

    ..some code..

    std::string filename = GetLoadFilename(nameID); //works

    std::ifstream infile;
    infile.open(filename, std::ios::binary);

    infile.read((char *)&myGame, sizeof(Game));

    if (infile.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "read failed" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << myGame->myMiner->getX(); //debug purposes : prints -842150451

    Play(myGame->myMiner->getX(), myGame->myMiner->getY());
}
```

Class Game:

```
class Game {

    Game *myGame;
    Miner *myMiner;
    BlockTypes *myBlockTypes;
    //Block* myBlocks[10000];
    Consola *myConsole;
    Mine *myMine;
    int linhas, colunas;
    int _currentStatus;

    public:
    ..some functions such as load & save
};
```

When loading, the "read failed" message is always shown, whats wrong ?

Comment: Without seeing the definition of `Game`, it's difficult to say exactly why.  I will say saving a binary image of a `struct` or `class` only tends to work when it's a POD type with no pointers.  And even then, it's not the most robust way to do things.  (It'll often break across platforms, for example, including between 32-bit and 64-bit x86 in many cases, depending on the contents of the struct.)

Comment: Hmm, i've added Game info. Basically is there a better to way to save all the data from a class like that in a file ?

Comment: Yeah, using `write` and `read` won't work with that structure at all.  :-)  Those pointers won't be valid, and you won't save the pointed-to data.  You'll want to look up the topic of _serialization._  Boost has a serialization library, though I've never used it.  Look here:    http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Otherwise, you'll have to write something custom that walks the structure and stores it, and something else custom that reads what you stored and creates/populates a new structure.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a struct with pointers writes the value of the pointers, not the value of the pointed objects.
You need to look into serialization. Serialization is a way to structure data onto a continuous unstructured medium like a hard drive. ie, how structure your info into a line of bits so you'll be able to reconstruct your objects from that same line of bits. the previously linked boost library is an option, but there is also [XML](http://www.allthingsc.net/2012/03/serializing-data-with-xml.html), [JSON](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/) and [other solutions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2269/what-are-good-solutions-for-serialization-in-c) that you should check out.

Answer (score 0):

The general way is to use "infile >> myGame".   In the Game class, define operator<< and operator>> to override the defaults with versions customized for your Game class.

These functions generally have a list of >> or << for each member of the class (which is the default if you don't define the operators). But you need to make some decisions and write some code for the pointer type members. The locations of objects in memory will move from run to run, so you can't just save and load pointer values.  For instance, maybe in Game::operator<< you need to call << on myMine to dump it (deep copy). But maybe Miner is a pointer into an array that is saved and loaded separately, so Game::operator<< saves a miner id number or name string and Game operator>> uses the saved data to look up the up the Miner to get the pointer.